# Application Pool Name displays as user in MVC application after publishing

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, publishing

Weird issue when publishing MVC application.

Using VS2015 with Update RC1, I have an MVC application using windows authentication.  My user name displays correctly on my dev work station.  But web server displays app pool name.  The application is really detecting me.  I have logic to display only records of the authenticated user.  But not sure how to get the name of authenticated user to display.
[image]

Comment: This project is a version of Contoso University that I'm trying to make it my own and created the project using Windows Authentication and learn the MVC mindset.  When I publish to dev-staging WinServer2012-vmWebServer, I use file system and push to a unique folder.

Comment: Then using IIS 8.5 I RtClk add application somewhere in my default web site and point it to the folder where I published the app.  
I then dbl click the Authentication icon in Features View in IIS and enable Windows Authentication.  
Not sure what default Doc to pick with these MVC apps, so I don't mess with this config.  I enabled Directory Browsing and selected the .NET v4.5 App pool.

Comment: These are the basic steps I use to setup my working version of contoso University.  
Today I created a new version Blank solution and then added a few class library Projects (Biz, Data, Common) and a MVC project that I will eventually config to use my class libraries again.  
When I publish this new app, my credentials display as expected.  Not sure why my other versions of contoso university display that darn App pool name.  
Very frustrating that I'm creating this same app all over again for about the 3rd time.  Actually, I've stopped counting ;(